# Does Church-Rosser theorem apply to call-by-value reduction?

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus, call-by-value

I've been studying the lambda calculus and recently saw the Church-Rosser theorem. The theorem states that when applying reduction rules to terms in the lambda calculus, the ordering in which the reductions are chosen does not make a difference to the eventual result (from wiki). But I find this inconsistent with call-by-value reduction and normal order reduction. For example, a lambda term λz.(λx.x) y can be reduced to λz.z when following the normal order reduction rules. But it cannot be further reduced when using call-by-value reduction because call-by-value reduction forbids reduction inside a λ-abstraction. So the term term λz.(λx.x) y cannot be evaluated to the same result using different rules, which seems to contradict to the Church-Rosser theorem. What's the problem here? Please help me out.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are being imprecise about the Church-Rosser theorem, and that's what is causing confusion.

As far as I have understood it (and I am writing this with ["The Implementation of Functional Programming Languages"](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/slpj-book-1987/) at hand), the theorem says the following:

> If two lambda expressions E and F are interconvertible by any sequence of reductions, then there exists an expression G, such that both E and F can be reduced to G.

From this follows only that one expression cannot have *two distinct normal forms* (although there might be *no* normal form at all). However, given two reductions orders, one might lead to an normal form, while the other one might diverge -- and some might even stop before, such as call-by-name.

Now, in your case, `E = \z.z` is in normal form, and `F = \z.((\x.x) z)`<sup>*</sup> can be reduced to it; the only thing that can be said here is that `F` cannot be reduced to anything else than `E`, while nothing is said about how much it has to be reduced.

There is also another part of the theorem, which says that if a normal form exists, normal order will find it. Again, no contradiction to your observation, since call-by-value and call-by-name might end up differently than normal order.

<sub><sup>*</sup>I assume you meant this insted of `\z.((\x.x) y)`, since the latter would make no sense.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've done some research since posed the question. Just like you said ain't the last paragraph, It seems that when Church proposed this theorem, there's only full beta reduction(or normal order maybe?). So the "reduction" in the theorem only referred to full beta reduction(or normal order). Other reducing strategy like call-by-name and call-by-value are for efficient implementation's sake.